# How do I remove 0 from end of stack

Tags: c++

The function processes a string array and returns an int value through the use of a stack function.
In a stack,the first number to be pushed is the last to be pop so the loop starts from the end of the string.
It is supposed to remove any 0's at the start of the string
Eg. 004912500 => 4912500 
but I have no idea how to ensure my loop is able to differentiate between 0's at the start and 0's after as the chars are all pushed from the back.
getVP returns integer value of void pointer

```
int getDecimal (const char stringOfDigits [])
{
    Stack S;
    int *temp;
    VoidPtr item;

    // Loop to get int value of each element of char array
    for (int i = strlen(stringOfDigits)-1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
                if (isdigit(stringOfDigits[i]))
                    {
                        if (stringOfDigits[i] != '0')
                            {
                                temp = new int;
                                *temp = (stringOfDigits[i] - '0');
                                item = temp;
                                S.push(item);
                            }                       
                    }
        }

    while(!S.isEmpty())
        {
            item = S.pop();
            cout << S.getVP(item);
        }

    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Your function does not return anything. What exactly is it supposed to accomplish?

Comment: it is supposed to return the int value after the pop but i left it as cout as i'm trying to fix the loop above

Comment: I meant, what is the expected relationship between the input and the output?

Comment: By the way, why are you storing `void` pointers in your stack if it's a stack of `int`s?

Comment: the input is a char string:
it is supposed to return a int value of the converted string.
If there are '0' char numbers in the front of the string,it is to be discarded
But if there are alphabets it is supposed to throw exception but i will implement it later.

Comment: But why are you messing around with stacks, then? There are countless examples online of how to convert strings to integers. (It's a straightforward loop and some basic arithmetic.)

Comment: I'm not following you at all, sorry.

Comment: BTW I don't think "alphabet" means what you think it means.

Comment: So much code, so little C++ in it. Where are `std::stack`, `std::string`, `std::vector` et al, which would probably turn all of this into a 3-liner?

Answer (score 0):

Skip the 0's before start to print them

```
int getDecimal (const char stringOfDigits [])
{
    Stack S;
    int *temp;
    VoidPtr item;

    int i = strlen(stringOfDigits)-1;

    // Loop to get int value of each element of char array
    for (; i >= 0; i--)
        {
                if (isdigit(stringOfDigits[i]))
                    {
                        if (stringOfDigits[i] != '0')
                            {
                                temp = new int;
                                *temp = (stringOfDigits[i] - '0');
                                item = temp;
                                S.push(item);
                            }                       
                    }
        }

    if(!S.isEmpty())
    {
        item = S.pop();
        //skip the 0's
        while((item == 0) && !S.isEmpty())
        {
            item = S.pop();
        }
        //output the first valid item, or a 0 if it's filled with 0 
        cout << S.getVP(item);

        while(!S.isEmpty())
        {
            item = S.pop();
            cout << S.getVP(item);
        }

    cout << endl;
}
```